# Error running React Native app - unknown option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

So I've been trying to learn react native for app development and I've been dealing with numerous errors trying to get a very simple app to run. I had to delete the node_modules and reinstall yarn. Now after solving the massive error that I was getting before, now when I try to run it I'm getting the following error in my cmd:

```
error: unknown option `--assetPlugins'

Metro Bundler process exited with code 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I found a similar question on here from earlier this year but the solution for that seemed to be properly updating the expo version, but my expo was installed literally a few days ago when I started a tutorial. Also the only code in my app.js file is the following:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const[outputText, setOutputText] = useState('New State');
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
<Text>{outputText}</Text>
      <Button title="Change Text" onPress={() => setOutputText('the text changed')}/>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

So I have no idea how to debug this, I am completely new to react. Thanks in advance for the help. I am getting so frustrated by react, I've been trying for over a week to get through a simple tutorial and I keep running into errors at every step of the way...

Comment: try deleting package-lock.json aswel

Comment: didnt help unfortunately...